# Apache Tomcat 6 Problem Not Found(404)

Tags: apache, tomcat

I am unable to open html page of my web application and getting error Not Found(404). Resource Not found.Also I am unable to open Tomacat Manger/Examples.
Checked that instance is already running whnen I try to configure or start manually. 
I donot have start.exe n stop.exe in my bin but having tomcat6.exe tomcat6w.exe as mentioned in steps at apache site.
Previously I used to face this problem and on pc restart it used to work but now its not working. Is there any problem with Apache installed on windows XP SP-2. Please tell me work aroud.

Comment: probably should be on serverfault.com

Comment: Have you looked in logs/localhost.2009-09-22.log ?

Answer (score 0):

Actually It was problem of port/socket that i used in my web.xml .
I must have used some port that was already being used. I removed that part of code from web.xml and now its running fine. Bu dont know reason why it doesnot work sometimes and i have to restart mu computer. It must be some wat related with mu automatic server startup.